# timedelta to float python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hi I have this column in dataframe which is like this:

```
Days
96 days
96 days
47 days
91 days
64 days
```

I wanted to plot it on the scatter plot, however I got the error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

Im pretty sure the problem lays in that column above, so I need to change it from this timedelta type to some plotable type, but not sure how can I do it? Any ideas?

Comment: How are you plotting it?

Comment: `plt.scatter(df.Days, V[:,0])`, where V is just an array of floats of the same size as that column

Comment: Matplotlib and bokeh understand timedeltas, so if it's plotting you want, you don't necessarily need to convert it

Comment: well but in this case it yielded error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to convert the Days column to integer format and plot as normal:

```
df['daysInt'] = df['Days'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

...will give you the int column, and you know the rest.

Comment: The subject line specifically asks for timedelta to float, and this yields an int, which loses a great deal of precision.

Comment: More than anything, the OP wanted a solution to his problem - which, according to the chosen answer indication, this gave.  And, given that he is starting with ints, no precision is lost with my answer.

Comment: While that may be true, I came across this while trying to plot using a time series with granularity of seconds, so the answer was not helpful, despite the subject line being a match for my problem.  Just to satisfy the next searcher who happens by here, what would the solution be for floats?

Comment: Ask a proper SO question and make a reference back to this one that it did not fully answer the stated question (to avoid duplicate question responses). You'll have an answer within 10 minutes.